# Is it possible to convert a C# string to a SqlChars?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gis

I'm creating some unit tests for a piece of code that returns a SqlGeography type.  To mock up the SqlGeography column I'd like to use [SqlGeography.STLineFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stlinefromtext.aspx) to create a line string.  Problem is STLineFromText takes SqlChars as a parameter.  Does anyone know how to convert a C# string to SqlChars?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
new SqlChars(new SqlString(text));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
new SqlChars(text.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [SqlChars constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bk0b18s.aspx):

```
SqlChars c = new SqlChars("test".ToArray());
```